# Why does vue-cli freeze when I try to create project?

Tags: vue.js

I use this command to create Vue project:

```
vue init webpack-simple <app-name>
```

but the screen gets frozen when it asks me to insert a description for the project the screen stays frozen on "desription" line:

```
C:\Users\KA>vue init webpack-simple apppp

? Project name apppp
? Project description (A Vue.js project)
```

**I tried different versions of node, v8, v10, v12,** and that did not solve my issue. So how did you solve this issue?

Comment: Hey, what if you try to do it with the gui, running the command `vue ui`? (Refer to https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create , "Using the GUI" section)

Comment: I did but nothing happened and even the browser did not open creation process. How do I troubleshoot this issue? - @LoïcMonard

Comment: always freeze when start vue create my-proj, but works fine with vue ui

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by the following steps:

1. I deleted all node.js versions from my computer.
2. I deleted npm-cache folder from this path `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming`
3. I rebooted my computer.
4. I installed node.js v6.8.1